# How to isolate two subnets from each other but allow Internet access for each

Tags: linux, iptables, firewalld

I have a server running as a gateway with three interfaces on their own networks:

- `enp1s0` - DHCP to Internet
- `enp2s0` - 172.16.0.1/12 to work LAN
- `enp3s0` - 10.0.0.1/8 for guest wireless

I want both `enp2s0` and `enp3s0` to access `enp1s0` (internet) and I want to block `enp3s0` (wireless) reaching anything in `enp2s0`. Is there a way to do this with `firewalld`? If not, with `iptables`?

Would this work?

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -d 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0 -j DROP
```

do I also need?

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -d 0.0.0/0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
```

For firewalld can I use

```
--add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=10.0.0.0/8 destination address=172.16.0.0/12 drop'
```

do I also need?

```
--add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=10.0.0.0/8 destination address=0.0.0.0 accept'
```

With these rules I can still ping a server in 172.16.0.0/12 network from 10.0.0.0/8. I would like nothing visible from the 10.0.0.0/8 network only the enp1s0 internet.

Comment: I want to block my wireless segment from reaching anything on my work LAN.

Answer (score 1):

```
# sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i ens3s0 -o ens2s0 -j DROP
```

This means that all traffic coming from **ens3s0** destined to **ens2s0** will be dropped.